# Check if mouse is still down

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have a drag'n'drop library that implements a delayed start of the dragging basically like this:

```
handleMouseDown = function () {
  dragtimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
    startDragging();
  }, 300);
};
handleMouseUp = function () {
  window.clearTimeout(dragtimer);
};
```

Now sometimes when the browser is busy, the timer event is handled *before* the mouseup event, although it was just a short click.

Is there a way to check inside the timer handler whether the mouse is *still* down or if there are any pending mouseup events to be handled?

Comment: i think that events are fired when something happend, you cant handle browser instance. George answer your question right with classic lock variable